# How can I stop execution of remainder of code on a frame? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, command

Using the goto command does not stop the current execution

for example if I have

```
gotoAndStop(2);
trace("1");
```

The application will still perform trace command and then move to frame 2. I would like to know if there is any such command that immediately ceases the execution of any code left in the frame?

Comment: The **return;** instruction will suffice.

Comment: yea that works, can you answer it so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the

```
return;
```

instruction to break the execution of the frame script.